# Nested Object deeping

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have data which contains nested object also.
For example sharing below the demo value.

```
const input = {
  a: 'jack',
  b: {
    c: 'sparrow',
    d: 'hahaha'
  }
}
```

Now i want all nested value at same level. Like this.

```
const input = {
  a: 'jack',
  c: 'sparrow',
  d: 'hahaha'
}
```

I have tried this but getting wrong output.

```
const getEntries = (o, prefix = '') => 
  Object.entries(o).flatMap(([k, v]) => 
    Object(v) === v  ? getEntries(v, `${prefix}${k}.`) : [ [`${prefix}${k}`, v] ]
  )

console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(getEntries(input))
)

output:-
{
a:"jack",
b.c:"sparrow",
b.d.e:"hahaha"
}
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Comment: @NinaScholz added my code kindly look. thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = {}

function unnest_obj(new_obj,obj){
  for (let x in obj) {
    if(typeof obj[x] === "object") unnest_obj(new_obj,obj[x])
    
    else new_obj[x] = obj[x]
  }
}

unnest_obj(output,input)
//console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the purpose of the question,

- to get all flat entries,
- return an object of entries.

`getFlatEntries` works as a recursiion fro neted objects and returns a flatt array of key/value pairs.

`getFlat` takes an object and returns the wanted flat object from flat entries

```js
const
    getFlatEntries = object => Object.entries(object).flatMap(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object' ? getFlatEntries(v) : [[k, v]]),
    getFlat = object => Object.fromEntries(getFlatEntries(object))
    input = { a: 'jack', b: { c: 'sparrow', d: 'hahaha', e: { f: 'most inner' } } },
    flat = getFlat(input);

console.log(flat);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    const flattenObject = (ob) => {
    var toReturn = {};
    for (var i in ob) {
        if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        
        if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
            var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
            for (var x in flatObject) {
                if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;
                toReturn[x] = flatObject[x];
            }
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return toReturn
}
```